# Spring Integration kafka outbound channel adapter

Tags: spring-integration, spring-kafka, spring-integration-dsl

I have a model object which is populated after several transformation and parsing. Now I need to send the message attribute within the model to kafka using spring integration. 
I am able to construct the key using the method messageKey but how can i get the actual message from the model like m.getPayload().getMessage() and send it to kafka.

```
                .publishSubscribeChannel(pubSub -> pubSub
                        .subscribe(flow -> flow
                            .bridge(e -> e.order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE))
                            .handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate).
                                    messageKey(m -> ((AcarsFlightInformation) m.getPayload()).getFlightNbr()).topic(acarsKafkaTopic)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking. The payload of the message sent to the adapter becomes the value of the producer record.

I think what you are asking is that you only want to send part of the payload.

Use a header enricher and transformer before the `.handle`...

```
.enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "payload.flightNumber")
.transform("payload.message")
.handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate)
      .topic(acarsKafkaTopic))
.get();
```

The adapter will look for that header for the key.